# Laravel API Policy returns 403

Tags: laravel, api, authorization

I'm trying to create policies for my Laravel API, so that only the the user can edit their own profile. Maybe these policies do not work the same way for API's.

Controller:

```php
public function updateProfile(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('updateProfile', $user->profile);
    
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'display_name' => 'required|unique:profiles',
    ]);
    
    if ($validator->fails())
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->messages()], 422);
    
    $user->profile->update($request->all());
    
    return response(['message' => 'Profile sucessfully updated']);
}
```

Policy

```php
public function updateProfile(User $user, Profile $profile)
{
    return $user->id === $profile->user_id;
}
```

AuthServiceProvider

```
protected $policies = [
    // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    Profile::class => ProfilePolicy::class
];
```

They return 403 errors. I'm thinking maybe I need to use requests, instead of the user models in the policy? like

```
 $request->user->id === $request->profile->user_id
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Have you registered the policy in the AuthServiceProvider class?

Comment: @reans Yes, i updated the post

Comment: before `return $user->id === $profile->user_id`, put a `dd("User {$user->id}, Profile user id {$profile->user_id}");` to make sure it's actually calling the policy and the values are correct.

Comment: @IGP Yes they return the values. User->id returns the user of which i am logged in to, and profile->user_id returns the user_id of the profile im trying to edit

Comment: And they are both the same? Try using `==` instead of `===` on the off chance there's a type difference. Also, try adding `dd()` before and after `$this->authorize()` to see if the Policy is the one causing this. Do you have any `Gate::before` or `Gate::after` callbacks defined?

Comment: == seemed to have done the trick, thanks!